# onesignal alert notification force close after open notification in ios

Tags: ios, angular, ionic3, onesignal

after open the notification from [notification center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgMR9.jpg), the application running only splash screen and force close after splash screen. my application in android is normal open [the alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPcIH.jpg). my ios version 12.2. my code is here:

```
initializeApp() 
  {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) 
      {

        this.oneSignal.startInit('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
        this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => this.onPushReceived(data.payload));
        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(data => this.onPushOpened(data.notification.payload));
        this.oneSignal.endInit();
}
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
}

  private onPushOpened(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: payload.additionalData.nodename,
      subTitle: 'My Note : '+payload.additionalData.title1+' <br/> '+'My Why  : '+payload.additionalData.mywhy,
      message: payload.body,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Utsett',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Det er utført',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('oke');
              this.responseData = result;
              this.nav.setRoot(MynotesPage, {id:payload.additionalData.id});
            });
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

I can't start intent right from "HandleNotificationOpened" function. Can anybody help me with this problem.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Can you try rephrasing?

Comment: Could you please include a pastebin link to your logs?